# Java 17 Drools - NullPointerException: : Cannot invoke "org.drools.compiler.compiler.Dialect.getId()" only happening on kubernetes

Tags: java, drools

I'm attempting to update my Java and Drools versions simultaneously (Java from 8 to 17 and Drools from 7.74.0-Final to 8.44.0-Final) and I've had some success locally (on IntelliJ), however when i try to run the same image on my minikube, the following error happens:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "org.drools.compiler.compiler.Dialect.getId()" because the return value of "org.drools.compiler.rule.builder.RuleBuildContext.getDialect()" is null
        at org.drools.compiler.rule.builder.RuleBuildContext.(RuleBuildContext.java:86)
        at org.drools.compiler.builder.impl.processors.ImmutableRuleCompilationPhase.buildRuleBuilderContext(ImmutableRuleCompilationPhase.java:259)
        at org.drools.compiler.builder.impl.processors.ImmutableRuleCompilationPhase.compileRulesLevel(ImmutableRuleCompilationPhase.java:297)
        at org.drools.compiler.builder.impl.processors.ImmutableRuleCompilationPhase.process(ImmutableRuleCompilationPhase.java:82)
        at org.drools.compiler.builder.impl.processors.RuleCompilationPhase.process(RuleCompilationPhase.java:91)
        at java.base/java.util.Arrays$ArrayList.forEach(Arrays.java:4204)
        at org.drools.compiler.builder.impl.KnowledgeBuilderImpl.compileKnowledgePackages(KnowledgeBuilderImpl.java:461)
        at org.drools.compiler.builder.impl.KnowledgeBuilderImpl.addPackageWithResource(KnowledgeBuilderImpl.java:446)
        at org.drools.compiler.builder.impl.KnowledgeBuilderImpl.addKnowledgeResource(KnowledgeBuilderImpl.java:377)
        at org.drools.compiler.builder.impl.KnowledgeBuilderImpl.add(KnowledgeBuilderImpl.java:919)
        at org.drools.compiler.builder.impl.KnowledgeBuilderImpl.add(KnowledgeBuilderImpl.java:908)
```

(for the record i have three drools knowledges being fed rules in parallel via CompletableFuture in case that is useful information)

I initialize each knowledge using the following code:

```
KieServices kieServices = KieServices.Factory.get();
KieFileSystem kieFileSystem = kieServices.newKieFileSystem();
KieBuilder kieBuilder = kieServices.newKieBuilder(kieFileSystem);
kieBuilder.buildAll();
KieModule kieModule = kieBuilder.getKieModule();
KieContainer kieContainer = kieServices.newKieContainer(kieModule.getReleaseId());
KieBaseConfiguration kieConfig = kieServices.newKieBaseConfiguration();
KnowledgeBuilderImpl knowledge = new KnowledgeBuilderImpl((InternalKnowledgeBase)     
kieContainer.newKieBase(kieConfig));
knowledge.addPackage(object.getPackageDescr());
```

I have no external files providing configurations or anything of the sort and I add rules to the knowledge utilizing the `KnowledgeBuilderImpl.add()` method as can be seen in the stack trace.

Is there any way i can specify the dialect without configuration files? (my rules are written in mvel)

And why is this only happening in my minikube but not on IntelliJ?

I've tried changing versions (downgrading from 8.44 whilst still staying on Drools 8), i've also read most of the documentation for the tools i'm using yet i didn't find a simple code-only way to set a dialect.

My pom at the moment has the current dependencies, all with the version 8.44.0-Final:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.kie</groupId>
        <artifactId>kie-api</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.drools</groupId>
        <artifactId>drools-core</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.drools</groupId>
        <artifactId>drools-compiler</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.drools</groupId>
        <artifactId>drools-mvel</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.drools</groupId>
        <artifactId>drools-ruleunits-engine</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.drools</groupId>
        <artifactId>drools-metric</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```